# Not able to connect to snowflakeDB

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

this is my code to connect to PG

```
database = f"postgresql://{db_config.get('user')}:{db_config.get('password')}@{db_config.get('host')}/{db_config.get('database')}"

db_connection_pool = create_engine(database, pool_size=config.get_connection_pool_size(), max_overflow=config.get_connection_overflow_size(), pool_ping=True)

session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=db_connection_pool, autocommit=False)



snowflake connection 

account='',
user='',
password='',
database='',
schema='',
warehouse='',
role='',

database = f"snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{database}/{schema}?warehouse={warehouse}&role={role}"

db_connection_pool = create_engine(database ,pool_size= config.get_connection_pool_size(), max_overflow=config.get_connection_overflow_size(), pool_ping=True)
connection = db_connection_pool.connect()
```

trying to change it to snowflake (new to it can someone help me)

Comment: Have you read the documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html ? If so, what specific issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Install the Snowflake Connector for Python](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html):

`pip install snowflake-connector-python==<version>`

2. Use this code for the Snowflake database connection:

```
import snowflake.connector

connection_parameters = {
    "user"          : 'MyUser',
    "password"      : 'MyPassword',
    "account"       : 'MyAccount',
    "role"          : 'MyRole',
    "warehouse"     : 'MyWarehouse',
    "database"      : 'MyDatabase',
    "schema"        : 'MySchema'
}

with snowflake.connector.connect(**connection_parameters) as connection:

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        # More python database code
```

Alternatively, you may want to save the connection parameters in a separate JSON file and use `json.load` to load them.